# How to build a dynamic linq expression tree in a loop

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following string arrray:

```
string[] ranges = new string[]{"0-100", "100-200", "500-1000"};
```

I would like to dynamically express this in a linq expression - Something along the lines of:

```
var query = from p in Db.Products()
            where p.Amount() >= 0
            where p.Amount() <= 100
            where p.Amount() >= 101
            where p.Amount() <= 200
            where p.Amount() >= 500
            where p.Amount() <= 1000
            select p;
```

I know how to extract the values from the array so that's not the issue, but more so how do i dynamically build the linq expression in a for loop:

```
string[] ranges = new string[]{"0-100", "100-200", "500-1000"};

foreach (var item in ranges)
{
    int min = int.Parse(item.Split('-').First());
    int max = int.Parse(item.Split('-').Last());                
    //Linq expression?
}
```

Comment: Note; be very very careful not to use `item` itself **directly** in any expression tree; that will capture the **variable**, not the value at any given iteration. The current approach obtaining `min` and `max` etc, and using **those** in the query is fine though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
IQueryable<Product> query = DB.Products();
foreach (var item in ranges)
{
    int min = int.Parse(item.Split('-').First());
    int max = int.Parse(item.Split('-').Last());                
    query = query.Where(p => p.Amount() >= min && p.Amount() <= max);
}
```

(I've only got half the where clauses you had, but it's equivalent. You can break it up if you really want.)

Note the assignment back to `query` - methods like `Where` return a *new* query which is the result of applying the operation to the *existing* query; they don't change anything in the existing query.

Comment: Can IEnumerable<T> be used over IQueryable<T>?

Comment: @Fixer: It depends where you want the query to be performed. Given the name, I assumed this was a LINQ to SQL query or something similar. If it's LINQ to Objects - or if you *want* the filtering to be done locally - then yes, you can absolutely use `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try out with following code:

```
           var result= from range in ranges
                       select new 
                       {
                           min = int.Parse(range.Split('-').First()),
                           max = int.Parse(range.Split('-').Last()) 
                       };
```

result contains all min and max....