# How to build a dynamic AND OR linq expression tree in a loop

Tags: c#, linq

Following on from a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718805/how-to-build-a-dynamic-linq-expression-tree-in-a-loop/9718896#9718896) question i asked, I'm now trying to figure out how to build dynamic expressions for both AND & OR queries.

Given the following string array:

```
string[] ranges = new string[]{"0-100", "100-200", "500-1000"};
```

I would like to dynamically express this in a linq expression - Something along the lines of:

```
var v = from p in products
        where 
        (p.Amount >= 0 && p.Amount <= 100) ||
        (p.Amount >= 101 && p.Amount <= 200) ||
        (p.Amount >= 500 && p.Amount <= 1000)
        select p;
```

How do i dynamically build the linq expression in this loop?

```
string[] ranges = new string[]{"0-100", "100-200", "500-1000"};

var query = products.AsQueryable();

foreach (var item in ranges)
{
    int min = int.Parse(item.Split('-').First());
    int max = int.Parse(item.Split('-').Last());                
    //Linq expression?
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
string[] ranges = new string[]{"0-100", "100-200", "500-1000"};
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

foreach (var item in ranges)
{
    int min = int.Parse(item.Split('-').First());
    int max = int.Parse(item.Split('-').Last());                
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Amount >= min && p.Amount <= max);
}
```

Notice how we start with the boolean state of `false`, and `or` together predicates in the loop.  Conversely, you can start with a state of `true` and `and` together the predicates.

Finally, not sure if this is possible with query comprehension syntax, but your ultimate query can then look like:

```
var v = products.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Thanks this led me onto the right track.  I ended up installing the nuget package LINQKit with includes predicate builder and more.  This is useful if you're working with EF objects.